# Subquery in FROM not working in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, subquery

I'm working on converting a query from having a subquery in the WHERE section to the FROM section.

As I understand it, the FROM clause will return a table, which I'm calling "product_locations" and then my outer query can retrieve information from that table. I can't see if the outer query is working at this point, because I'm getting stuck on an error that I'm missing a right parenthesis. 
At this point, I think my main problem is not understanding how to properly identify the two parts of an IN clause that constitutes the subquery.

Here is the original query:

```
SELECT size_option, 
       product.product_name
FROM   sizes
JOIN   available_in ON sizes.sized_id = available_in.sizes_id
JOIN   product ON product.product_id = available_in.product_id
WHERE (SELECT COUNT (store_name)
       FROM store_location IN (SELECT COUNT (store_location_id)
       FROM sells
       JOIN product ON sells.product_id = product.product_id
       GROUP BY sells.store_location)
```

This is the query I'm attempting:

```
SELECT size_option, 
       product_location.product_name 
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(store_name)
       FROM   store_location) IN (SELECT COUNT (store_location_id)
       FROM sells
       JOIN product ON sells.product_id = product.product_id
GROUP BY sells.store_location_id) product_location
JOIN   sizes ON sizes.size_option = product_location.size_option
JOIN   available_in ON sizes.sizes_id = available_in.sizes_id
JOIN   product ON product.product_id = available_in.product_id
```

and the error I'm getting:

```
SELECT size_option, 
       product_location.product_name 
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(store_name)
       FROM   store_location) IN (SELECT COUNT (store_location_id)
       FROM sells
       JOIN product ON sells.product_id = product.product_id
GROUP BY sells.store_location_id) product_location
JOIN   sizes ON sizes.size_option = product_location.size_option
JOIN   available_in ON sizes.sizes_id = available_in.sizes_id
JOIN   product ON product.product_id = available_in.product_id
Error at Command Line : 4 Column : 31
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Here's a picture of the error in my editor
[image: picture of the error]

Here's the ERD 
[image]

Comment: `IN` is not recognized in a `FROM` clause.  It is rather hard to tell what your intention is.

Comment: The query in the `FROM` clause is called a "Table Expression". Table expressions must be named, as in `select * from (select ...) x`. See the `x`?

Comment: Now, in the original query the subquery is a "correlated" subquery. A typical table expression does not accept those, unless you create a "lateral table expression". It's becoming uglier by the minute. Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: The intention is to show all products that are available in all locations. The purpose of the IN statement is that the first COUNT `(SELECT COUNT(store_name)
       FROM   store_location)` counts the number of stores, and the second `(SELECT COUNT (store_location_id)
       FROM sells
       JOIN product ON sells.product_id = product.product_id
GROUP BY sells.store_location_id) product_location` counts the number of stores each product is available in, so if the first number is contained in the second query, the result will be selected.

Comment: Your original query is very interesting as it does not maintain any boolean expression. In fact it would always return TRUE if subquery does not return NULL, similar to `WHERE 1`.

Comment: @TheImpaler Unfortunately, the reason I want to do this is because my grad school database professor is a sadist. I'm a network guy taking a database class!

Comment: *The intention is to show all products that are available in all locations* ... what is the *available_in* table?

Comment: @Parfait I've added the ERD to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an [IN condition](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions014.htm) in a FROM clause is likely to give you grief, as 
"A condition specifies a combination of one or more expressions and logical (Boolean) operators and returns a value of TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN."
(see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions.htm)).  Thus, a construct like (SELECT ...) IN (SELECT ...) - if syntactically correct - will return true, false, or unknown - which is useful in a WHERE clause (not in a FROM clause).

In one of your comments, you are explaining that ...
" The intention is to show all products that are available in all locations."

Using a small test data set (see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=14535f6722f7d0d61eb9ba3f57f6eab1)), encompassing 5 of your tables, the following query may give you
a starting point for finding the solution:

```
-- Find the store count for each product (table SELLS)
-- and return all product_ids that are available everywhere (STORE_LOCATION count)

select product_id
from (
  select 
    product_id
  , count( store_location_id ) store_count
  from sells
  group by product_id
  having count( store_location_id ) = ( select count(*) from store_location )
) ;

-- result
PRODUCT_ID
----------
        10
```

Alternative

```
-- ---------------------------------------------------
-- use analytics -> we don't need GROUP BY and HAVING
-- ---------------------------------------------------
-- 1  count all store_locations (SL)
-- 2  count the amount of stores a product is located in (S)
-- 3  JOIN the 2 result sets (equijoin)
-- 4  return the product_id found
-- NOTE: we are working with Oracle -> don't use AS when defining table aliases (AS can be used for column aliases)

select product_id -- 4
from ( 
  select count(*) store_count from store_location  -- 1
) SL join (
  select unique 
    product_id
  , count( store_location_id ) over ( partition by product_id ) store_count -- 2
  from sells
) S on SL.store_count = S.store_count -- 3
;

-- result
PRODUCT_ID
----------
        10
```

Once you get the correct product_id(s), you can "bolt on" the remaining tables needed for your query (using JOINs) and write all required column names (including table aliases) into the SELECT.
E.g.

```
select 
  S.product_id
, P.product_name
, SZ.size_option
from ( 
  select count(*) store_count from store_location 
) SL join (
  select unique
    product_id
  , count( store_location_id ) over ( partition by product_id ) store_count
  from sells
) S on SL.store_count = S.store_count 
join product P       on S.product_id = P.product_id
join available_in AI on AI.product_id = P.product_id 
join sizes SZ        on AI.sizes_id = SZ.sizes_id
;

-- result
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_N SIZE_OP
---------- --------- -------
        10 product10 option1
        10 product10 option2
```

Answer (score 0):

you query may like below

```
SELECT size_option, 
       product_location.product_name,
      (
       SELECT COUNT(store_name)
       FROM   store_location
       )  as store_name_cnt,
       (
       SELECT COUNT (store_location_id)
       FROM sells
       JOIN product ON sells.product_id = product.product_id
    GROUP BY sells.store_location_id
     ) as location_count
    from product_location
JOIN   sizes ON sizes.size_option = product_location.size_option
JOIN   available_in ON sizes.sizes_id = available_in.sizes_id
```

your query error

```
SELECT size_option, 
       product_location.product_name 
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(store_name) --invalid from 
       FROM   store_location) 
      IN (SELECT COUNT (store_location_id) -- there is no where but you use in
       FROM sells
       JOIN product ON sells.product_id = product.product_id
GROUP BY sells.store_location_id) product_location -- inconsistent table alias
JOIN   sizes ON sizes.size_option = product_location.size_option
JOIN   available_in ON sizes.sizes_id = available_in.sizes_id
JOIN   product ON product.product_id = available_in.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the OP in comments: *The intention is to show all products that are available in all locations.*

Consider joining two aggregate query derived tables (or subqueries in `FROM` or `JOIN` clause):

1. one that counts stores at specific product
2. one that counts stores across all products

Then join the subqueries by corresponding *product_id* and *store_count* value. Be sure to use table aliases for readability.

```
SELECT s.size_option, 
       p.product_name
FROM   sizes AS s
JOIN   available_in AS a ON s.sized_id = a.sizes_id
JOIN   product AS p ON p.product_id = a.product_id
JOIN  
      --- STORE COUNT BY PRODUCT
      (
       SELECT sub_p.product_id, COUNT(sl.store_location_id) AS store_count
       FROM sells AS sl
       JOIN product AS sub_p ON sl.product_id = sub_p.product_id
       GROUP BY sub_p.product_id
      ) AS agg_p 
  ON agg_p.product_id = p.product_id

JOIN  
      --- STORE COUNT ACROSS ALL PRODUCTS
      (
       SELECT COUNT(sl.store_location_id) AS store_count
       FROM sells AS sl
       JOIN product AS sub_p ON sl.product_id = sub_p.product_id
      ) AS agg_s 
  ON agg_s.store_count = agg_p.store_count
```